# CakePHP: Database Association 1-to-Many link to 1-to-1

Tags: cakephp, model, associations, table-relationships

> 3 tables:

```
PaymentRequests
PaymentPurchaseOrders
PurchaseOrders
```

> Current Relationship:

```
PaymentRequests -> HasMany -> PaymentPurchaseOrders -> BelongsTo ->PurchaseOrders
```

> Current Codes on Controller:

```
$Get = $this->PaymentRequests->find(
    'all', [
        'contain'=>['PaymentPurchaseOrder'=>['PurchaseOrder']
    ]);
```

> Problem:

This is too heavy a query. I want to just associate this in model but i do not know how.

Comment: you can write `'contain'=>['PaymentPurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrders']` to simplify a bit, but I don't see the point. Can you please explain what exactly is too heavy?

Comment: Too much data on PaymentPurchaseOrders cause the system to be slow. That's why I want to implement the association on the model side.

Comment: you can choose what columns you want to retrieve to limit the data. Just use `select()`

Comment: I limited the fields already using, 'fields'=>['id'] but data is just too large,

Comment: Then process it chunks. Simple and logical consequence.

Comment: is it not possible to do this in the model ??
maybe use HMABT, [Has Many And Belongs To]   ??

Comment: I already cached my query.

Comment: Your query is not the problem, the problem is that you're fetching *ALL* data with the given conditions. If you have more data returned than php is allowed to consume memory you run out of memory or it simply takes the request to long to complete and it gets interrupted because the maximum runtime of a request is probably limited to 30 or 60sec depending on your config. Increasing this is *not* a solution, simply batch process the data. You might want to learn about how data is stored and processed in a computer system.

Comment: In my real codes, i already limited the fields using, ['fields']=>['id', 'created']   and so on... I disregarded that on my question to make the question less complicated.